# Excel : If cell has a value write value into next cell in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a formula or connection in excel where if cell A2 has value entered should copy the same value into cell D2 , now enter new value into cell A2 , should add this new value in cell D3 or else D2 but still retaining the earlier value to D3 .Overall all the values entered in the cell A2 should keep storing in Column D .

Comment: I don't see it happening without the use of `VBA`. If that is a possibility, you should add the `vba` tag or just confirm (someone will add it for you). Also, you should clarify what should happen if one of the previously added values is entered: should it be added again or not?

Comment: I dont want to use VB is there a way doing this only within excel ?

Comment: you want what? break it down: step 1) Enter value into A2. Step 2) it should be copied into D2. Step 3) Enter new value into A2. Step 4) ????